# CSS Handling overflow of div

Tags: css, html, window, inline

I have a problem with 2 divs.

Its a box with 100% width that has 2 divs. Left one is a thumbnail image. Right one is description.

My problem is that when you resize your browser window, data description goes below thumbnail. I've added min-width with no results. Maybe I'm adding it in the wrong place.

Thanks a lot.

http://jsfiddle.net/NzX9e/

Comment: Can you reduce your example to the bare minimum of markup necessary to demonstrate the problem? You have so many elements that I'm not sure which ones you're having trouble with.

Comment: Yes sorry, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NzX9e/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix % values with fixed widths if you want things to work properly as you scale your window. A div will naturally take all the space given it by the parent. So what you really need to do here is drop a lot of all the unnecessary styles and markup you have.

For this specific case: http://jsfiddle.net/NzX9e/7/

Basically, you float the div containing the img and remove all the other styles on the one beside it (I added some padding to it to give it a bit of breathing room next to the image).

```
.docBox {
   border: solid 1px #006633;
   margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
   overflow: hidden;   <- this acts like a clear to keep the floated div in the parent
}

.previewImgBox {
   height: 70px;
   width: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
}

.previewData {
    padding: 0 0 0 60px;
    'all the styles you had here are not needed and cause your problem'
}
```

I wasn't about to go through and clean up all the markup and styles, just calling it out that you have a lot more than needed. Probably more than double for what you are trying to accomplish. Less is more. :)

Comment: Thanks, why you prefer floating image instead of 2 inline divs? I'm novice on this and that's something I don't understand, there must be a reason.

In previewdata I had overflow:auto because I wan't a fixed height and put a scroll bar for keywords if there's overflow. In your fiddle it isn't working if I add it... is it because of parent having overflow: hidden?

Comment: Not sure why you want a fixed height, having a scroll bar appear on every text block would be annoying. You can add it back in if you like. Inline implies the elements size to their content, what you actually want is a box layout (the most common in my experience). You'll find with css and html you can get things to bahave almost anyway you want, but the proper way will always lead to the cleanest solution and least amount of code. I had a response written here to try to describe the reasoning but the field isn't big enough. Simply put, play to the strengths of the elements natural behavior.

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzX9e/11/

Changes include:

Remove the margin-top:

```
.previewImgBox .thumb {
    /*margin-top: 5px;*/
}
```

Add height:

```
.docBox {
    height: 70px;
    border: solid 1px #006633;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

Add float:left:

```
.previewData {
    height: 70px;
    min-width: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    /*border: solid 1px #00CC33;*/
    overflow: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.previewImgBox {
    height: 70px;
    width: 50px;
    /*border: solid 1px #00CC33;*/
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm its even more broken than my first example :P Its going outside container div.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I will ask you the same question that I did on the other reply: Why you prefer floating image instead of 2 inline divs? More for curiosity than other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just modified the 95% width to 94% and it worked like a charm. I hope question can stay open to see if there's a better solution.